# Regex for matching the accent characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a word with accent or without accent in french language

Example: **Pere** and **Père** or **à** and **a**

Now im using this simple regex ((?!.*\b\1\b) is for not match 2 times the same word)

```
(pere|mère|a)(?!.*\b\1\b)
```

Im using new Regex in Javascript

```
new RegExp("(pere|mère|a)(?!.*\\b\\1\\b)", 'gi')
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the goal of this? Are you trying to remove accents (to sanitize a URL for exemple) ?

Comment: Not remove just search the word with `var regex = new RegExp("(pere)(?!.*\\b\\1\\b)", 'gi'); "père".match(regex)`

Comment: Note that `à` is not a word character, so the wordboundary `\b` doesn't work for it as it would for `a`. If you want to have that negative lookahead for `[aà]` then you probably first have to replace all the `à` by `a` and then run such a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define **character classes** then, e.g.:

```
p[èe]re
```

This can be seen as an alternation like

- Match **p**
- Match **è** or **e**
- Match **r** and **e**

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rOsrX8/1).

Comment: Thanks you but i need same for all words with accent (père, mère, à, français, ...) who i can do this ?

Comment: @Miky: Won't work, the character `è` (138) is simply not the same as `e` (101), see the [ASCII table](http://www.chip.de/ii/1/2/5/4/9/5/8/0/ascii-93c823e7009f26b0.png).